# Doxygen's FORMULA_MACROFILE not reading the macrofile

Tags: latex, doxygen, mathjax

in some LaTeX projects I want to use a file with some \newcommand instructions that make it easier (or at least quicker) to write linear algebra equations. So I copied that file into my project and setup a Doxyfile with the variable `FORMULA_MACROFILE` set to `macros.inc`

Now if I use a command that is defined in `macros.inc` doxygen is not able to use these commands neither with using latex nor mathjax.

This is my doxfile

```
PROJECT_NAME           = <...>                                                                    
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = <...>
INPUT                  = <...>
RECURSIVE              = YES
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES

CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES 
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 50  
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES              
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 100
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0                                                                              
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES                                                                            
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = svg                                 
                                                                                                        
USE_MATHJAX            = YES                                                                            
FORMULA_MACROFILE      = macros.inc   
                                                                  
GENERATE_HTML  = YES
GENERATE_XML   = NO
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
```

With some short `macros.inc` it is not working either:

```
\newcommand{\mA}{\mathbf{A}}
```

`macros.inc` is in the same directory as Doxyfile!

Now if I let doxygen generate the html doc it does not complain about anything but when viewing the page that used the latex command `\mA` mathjax complains with the error `Undefined control sequence \mA`

I could not find any example Doxyfile that actually uses `FORMULA_MACROFILE`. Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Which version of MathJax?

Comment: I tried the sequence `\f$ \mA \f$` and had no problem. Where did you see the warning?

Comment: > Which version of doxygen? Which version of MathJax?

I am using doxygen 1.9.1. Doxygen generated the following for mathjax:
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js"></script>

Comment: The warning appears in the browser (chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it...
It seems there may not appear any spaces in the declaration of commands.

This does **not** work (note the gap):

```
\newcommand{\mA} {\mathbf{A}}
```

This **does** work:

```
\newcommand{\mA}{\mathbf{A}}
```

Comment: Did you also get the warning: `warning: file contains non valid code, expected '[' or '{' got ' '` on the macro file? Doxygen is a bit more restrictive than LaTeX itself at this point.